# How to manage the parameters by default in the definitions of the discord commands

Tags: python, discord.py

In fact I wanted to repeat a defined number of times the written sentence with the parameter: "async def say(ctx, repetition, *phrase) but I would like in fact when we specify only the sentence in the command, by default the number of repetition is 1 and gives this: async def say(ctx, repetition = 1, *phrase) the problem is that when entering the command in discord for example: "!say Hello my name is Leo" It takes the Hello as the repetition parameter, I don't really know if I'm clear

I would like to make discord understand that in "!say hi how are u ?" repetition is by default 1 and that Hi corresponds to the parameter "sentence" and that on the other hand in "!say 5 Hi how are u ?" there 5 corresponds to repetition. I don't know if is possible..

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: just check `try: int(args[0])` and if it goes through then `sentence = " ".join(args[1:])` and `rep = int(args[0])` else do `rep = 1` and `sentence = " ".join(args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`discord.py` supports the `Optional` and `Union` typehints for parsing arguments.

You can set the `repetition` argument to `Optional[int]` so if the user doesn't provide an integer as the first argument `discord.py` won't throw an error when parsing.

```py
from typing import Optional

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, repetition: Optional[int] = 1, *, phrase):
    for _ in range(repetition):
        await ctx.send(phrase)
```

I also used the keyword-only argument (`*`) so it already takes the `phrase` argument as a string, not a tuple.

##### References:

- [Special converters, `typing.Optional`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional)
- [Keyword-only arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)